# flask file download method not allowed error

Tags: file, web, methods, flask, download

flask code

```
@app.route('/usecase/get/excel/<heads>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_excel(heads):
    headers = {"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=%s" % "usecase.xls"}
    with open("usecase.xls", 'r') as f:
        body = f.read()
    return Response(response=(body, headers))
```

html code

```
<form action="/template/usecase/get/excel/" method="post">     
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">download</button>
</form>
```

if click download button, error occured "Method not allowed"..
and how to download server's file? this is exactly program?

Answer (score 2):

Are you matching the right route?
`/template/` does not seem to be part of your routing rules unless its some root prefix. Secondly the `heads` attribute is not optional so you will not hit that route anyway with that request.

On a more picky note: Why are you using a POST request to fetch the data when you clearly imply that you support the GET version.